# Custom shape tappable area with CustomPaint widget on Flutter

Tags: flutter

I’ve seen some posts with things similar to this question, but they’re not what I’m looking for. I want to create a button with a custom shape in Flutter. For that I use a CustomPaint widget inside a GestureDetector widget. The problem is that I don’t want invisible areas to be tappable. And that's exactly what happens with the GestureDetector. In others words, I just want my created shape to be tappable. But right now it seems that there's an invisible square where my custom shape is, and that is also tappable. I don't want that. The most similar issue I found in this post:

[Flutter - Custom button tap area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54172312/flutter-custom-button-tap-area)

however, in my case I’m dealing with custom shapes and not with squares or circles.

Let me share with you the code and an example image of a possible button. You could just copy it and paste it direct on your main. It should be easy to replicate my problem.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Custom Shapes',
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Custom Shapes App'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white24,
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          child: CustomPaint(
            size: Size(300,300), //You can Replace this with your desired WIDTH and HEIGHT
            painter: RPSCustomPainter(),
          ),
          onTap: (){
            print("Working?");
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class RPSCustomPainter extends CustomPainter{

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {



    Paint paint_0 = new Paint()
      ..color = Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 150, 243)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..strokeWidth = 1;
    paint_0.shader = ui.Gradient.linear(Offset(0,size.height*0.50),Offset(size.width,size.height*0.50),[Color(0xffffed08),Color(0xffffd800),Color(0xffff0000)],[0.00,0.34,1.00]);

    Path path_0 = Path();
    path_0.moveTo(0,size.height*0.50);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width*0.33,size.height*0.33);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width*0.50,0);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width*0.67,size.height*0.33);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width,size.height*0.50);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width*0.67,size.height*0.67);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width*0.50,size.height);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width*0.33,size.height*0.67);
    path_0.lineTo(0,size.height*0.50);
    path_0.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path_0, paint_0);


  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }

}
```

I'd try that the star is the only tappable thing, and no other invisible place on the screen.

[image: Star button]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need a custom `ShapeBorder` class, and pass it to `RaisedButton.shape`

Answer (score 5):

There are for now two solutions so far, the first one is just by overriding hitTest of CustomPainter class, however the behavior is not the most desired. Because you don't have any splashcolor or similar when tapping. So here is the first one:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
        body: Center(
          child: TappableStarButton(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TappableStarButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: GestureDetector(
        child: CustomPaint(
          size: Size(300, 300),
          painter: RPSCustomPainter(),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          print("This works");
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RPSCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
  Path path_0 = Path();

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint_0 = new Paint()
      ..color = Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 150, 243)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..strokeWidth = 1;
    paint_0.shader = ui.Gradient.linear(
        Offset(10, 150),
        Offset(290, 150),
        [Color(0xffff1313), Color(0xffffbc00), Color(0xffffca00)],
        [0.00, 0.69, 1.00]);

    path_0.moveTo(150, 10);
    path_0.lineTo(100, 100);
    path_0.lineTo(10, 150);
    path_0.lineTo(100, 200);
    path_0.lineTo(150, 290);
    path_0.lineTo(200, 200);
    path_0.lineTo(290, 150);
    path_0.lineTo(200, 100);
    canvas.drawPath(path_0, paint_0);
  }

  @override
  bool hitTest(Offset position) {
    bool hit = path_0.contains(position);
    return hit;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

And it works. The problem is that you don't see any behavior when you tap on the "button".

The other solution, and way better, is by using Material with an Inkwell for your button. And for your shape, ShapeBorder class.

**Without null safety**

Here it is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black38,
        body: StarButton(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class StarButton extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        height: 300,
        width: 300,
        child: Material(
          shape: StarShape(),
          color: Colors.orange,
          child: InkWell(
            splashColor: Colors.yellow,
            onTap: () => print('it works'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class StarShape extends ShapeBorder {
  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => null;

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {ui.TextDirection textDirection}) => null;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {ui.TextDirection textDirection}) =>
      null;

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) => null;

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {ui.TextDirection textDirection}) {
    return Path()
      ..moveTo(150, 10)
      ..lineTo(100, 100)
      ..lineTo(10, 150)
      ..lineTo(100, 200)
      ..lineTo(150, 290)
      ..lineTo(200, 200)
      ..lineTo(290, 150)
      ..lineTo(200, 100)
      ..close();
  }
}
```

**With null safety:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

void main() {
  runApp(const App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black38,
        body: StarButton(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class StarButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const StarButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 300,
        width: 300,
        child: Material(
          shape: StarShape(),
          color: Colors.orange,
          child: InkWell(
            customBorder: StarShape(),
            splashColor: Colors.yellow,
            onTap: () => print('it works'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class StarShape extends ShapeBorder {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {ui.TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    return;
  }

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {ui.TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    return Path()
      ..moveTo(150, 10)
      ..lineTo(100, 100)
      ..lineTo(10, 150)
      ..lineTo(100, 200)
      ..lineTo(150, 290)
      ..lineTo(200, 200)
      ..lineTo(290, 150)
      ..lineTo(200, 100)
      ..close();
  }

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => EdgeInsets.zero;

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) => Path();

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) => StarShape();
}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: and how do you see that button was tapped? do you have any indication that you tapped the button? no, but with InkWell you clearly see that you tapped the button, so what is better with CustomPaint?

Comment: You have a good point. In my point of view, it's easier to create the form with custom paint, but still, the issue with Inkwell is indeed better, as you said.

Comment: honestly, why CustomPaint is easier? in both cases you have to create the same Path...

Comment: I don't doubt it. I just have to understand better ShapeBorder. For instance, how would you create the star form with this: 

Path()
      ..moveTo(150, 10)
      ..lineTo(100, 100)
      ..lineTo(10, 150)
      ..lineTo(100, 200)
      ..lineTo(150, 290)
      ..lineTo(200, 200)
      ..lineTo(290, 150)
      ..lineTo(200, 100)
      ..close();

in this class.

Comment: I changed the path as you said and it works. Just have some weird behavior, where my button appears at the upper left corner. Even if was using center widget.

Comment: But yes, so far, considering the inkwell thing your solution is better. I'm changing my answer as soon as I manage the weird behavior.

Comment: I did it. Great. Thanks a lot pskink. Really

Comment: is there a null safety version of this?

Comment: I'll take some time to update my answer. Thank you for the recommendation.

Comment: I've just posted the null safety version :)

Answer (score 3):

With help of this issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60143 and the hint given that I should use a RaisedButton with a custom shape I was able solve the problem. I did some changes to the code posted on github. Mine wasn't the best to start with. There are other better options than using a CustomPaint widget with a GestureDetector.

Here you have the code. You should be able to see that if you tap anywhere outside the shape given, the print statement will not be triggered.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(body: Center(child: BuyTicketButton(100.0, ()=>{})))
    );
  }
}

class BuyTicketButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final double cost;
  final Function onTap;

  const BuyTicketButton(this.cost, this.onTap, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        height: 400,
        child: RaisedButton(
          shape: CustomBorder(),
          onPressed: (){
            print("this works");
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class CustomBorder extends OutlinedBorder {

  const CustomBorder({
    BorderSide side = BorderSide.none
  }) : assert(side != null), super(side: side);

  Path customBorderPath(Rect rect) {
    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, 0);
    path.lineTo(rect.width, 0);
    path.lineTo(rect.width, rect.height);
    path.lineTo(0, rect.height);

    double diameter = rect.height / 3;
    double radius = diameter / 2;

    path.lineTo(0, diameter * 2);
    path.arcToPoint(
      Offset(0, diameter),
      radius: Radius.circular(radius),
      clockwise: false,
    );
    path.lineTo(0, 0);
    return path;
  }


  @override
  OutlinedBorder copyWith({BorderSide side}) {
    return CustomBorder(side: side ?? this.side);
  }

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => EdgeInsets.all(side.width);

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
    return customBorderPath(rect);
  }

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
    return customBorderPath(rect);
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
    switch (side.style) {
      case BorderStyle.none:
        break;
      case BorderStyle.solid:
        canvas.drawPath(customBorderPath(rect), Paint()
          ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
          ..color = Colors.black
          ..strokeWidth = 1.0
        );
    }
  }

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) => CustomBorder(side: side.scale(t));

}
```

This is the image you will be seeing. There, if you now tap on the half empty circle, you'll see nothing will happen. That's what I was expecting.

[image: Image to test tapping]

Nonetheless, I would recommend reading my other answer, which is for me so far better than this one.

Comment: btw you can also use `OutlineButton` or `FlatButton` or even raw `Material` widget but in that case you need a `InkWell` too, for more see *EDIT2* here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57943257/2252830

Comment: It's interesting, but I have to say, I'm still struggling with it nonetheless. Say, if I want to create for instance a tappable triangle and nothing outside it, I'm thinking this is not possible, because it seems that one needs to always have a rectangle as the basis. What do you think? In the custompaint class there's always this Rect object.

Comment: just trangle? so it is simple `Path.moveTo` and `Path.lineTo` and `Path.lineTo` and `Path.close`

Comment: yes to create the form is simple. But to determine that the only tappable area is in fact this triangle is what I'm looking for

Comment: Actually, I correct myself, what I wanted to say is that the customBorder always requires a Rect object.

Comment: strange, in fact `RaisedButton` only shows the shape but you can tap anywhere (i need to check it why...), but see: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gjgVszpwhC/ - this is strange since `RawMaterialButton` (which is used by `RaisedButton`) uses the same widgets when building itself: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/2783f8e2e1/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/button.dart#L416

Comment: So I tried with TriangleShape but if you look closely it seems that there's again a rectangle where your triangle is. I tapped above and below the triangle, and the print statement still got triggered.

Comment: Did you use the test code from the top comment? https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gjgVszpwhC/ lines 2-8

Comment: You're right. Sorry, didn't see it cause it was commented. Now I tried and it works fine! If I understand well, this should work also for creating any custom shape, right?

Answer (score 2):

A `GestureDetector` is hit (and start detecting) when its child says it is hit (unless you chance its `behavior` property).
To specify when `CustomPaint` is hit, `CustomPainter` has a `hitTest(Offset)` method that you can override. It should return whether the `Offset` should be consider inside your shape. Unfortunately, the method doesn’t have a size parameter. (That’s a bug which solution has hit some inertia, see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28206)
The only good solution is to make a custom render object in which you override the paint and hitTestSelf methods (in the latter, you can use the objects `size` property).

For example:

```dart
class MyCirclePainter extends LeafRenderObjectWidget {
  const MyCirclePainter({@required this.radius, Key key}) : super(key: key);

  // radius relative to the widget's size
  final double radius;

  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) => RenderMyCirclePainter()..radius = radius;

  @override
  void updateRenderObject(BuildContext context, RenderMyCirclePainter renderObject) => renderObject.radius = radius;
}

class RenderMyCirclePainter extends RenderBox {
  double radius;

  @override
  void performLayout() {
    size = constraints.biggest;
  }

  @override
  void performResize() {
    size = constraints.biggest;
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    final center = size.center(offset);
    final r = 1.0 * radius * size.width;
    final backgroundPaint = Paint()
      ..color = const Color(0x88202020)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    context.canvas.drawCircle(center, r, backgroundPaint);
  }

  @override
  bool hitTestSelf(Offset position) {
    final center = size.center(Offset.zero);
    return (position - center).distance < size.width * radius;
  }
}
```

Note that the top-left of the widget is at the `offset` parameter in the `paint` method, instead of the `Offset.zero` it is in `CustomPainter`.

You probably want to construct the path once and use `path_0.contains(position)` in `hitTestSelf`.

Comment: You're right @spkersten this solution worked perfectly. I'm posting the code with the corrected code.

Comment: There's only the thing with some desirable behavior when tapping on the button. One would maybe want some splashcolor. Gesture Detector doesn't give you that. But apart from that, this is a very acceptable solution.