# Flutter: how to add border for custom shape tappable button

Tags: flutter

I created a triangle shaped button using the instructions in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65705475/10946895

I am planning to arrange them into 6 triangles that form a hexagon. I would like to add some space between without messing up the shape. how do I go about it?

```
class TriangleButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final double _side;

  const TriangleButton(this._side, {super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var height = sqrt(3) / 2 * _side;
    var offsets = [
      Offset(_side / 2, 0),
      Offset(0, height),
      Offset(_side, height)
    ];
    return SizedBox(
      height: _side,
      width: _side,
      child: Material(
        shape: TriangleShape(offsets),
        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        child: InkWell(
          customBorder: TriangleShape(offsets),
          splashColor: Colors.orange,
          onTapDown: (details) {
            dev.log('Tap down: ${details.localPosition}');
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class TriangleShape extends ShapeBorder {
  List<Offset> _offsets = [];
  final List<Offset> _inOffsets = [];

  TriangleShape(List<Offset> offsets) {
    _offsets = offsets;
    _inOffsets.add(Offset(offsets[0].dx, offsets[0].dy+30));
    _inOffsets.add(Offset(offsets[1].dx+30, offsets[0].dy-30));
    _inOffsets.add(Offset(offsets[2].dx-30, offsets[0].dy-30));
  }
  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => const EdgeInsets.all(0);

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    rect.deflate(10);
    return Path()..addPolygon(_inOffsets, false);
  }

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    return Path()..addPolygon(_offsets, false);
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    return;
  }

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) => TriangleShape(_offsets);
}
```

Wrapping the button with padding doesn't have the intended effect. Edit: Also tried adding `_inOffsets` brining in the InnerPath by 30, and returning the Path to `getInnerPath()`.
`rect.deflate()` is not helping either.

I feel like I am missing something obvious.

```
Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const TriangleButton(side),
                Transform.translate(
                  offset: const Offset(-side, 0),
                  child: Transform.rotate(
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                      angle: -pi/3,
                      child: const TriangleButton(side)),
                ),
              ],
            )
```

[image: Both triangles are shown without a border]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a way to do it. Instead of using transforms, I used different offsets to draw the triangle shape/direction I wanted.

I had to use SizedBox with a Stack widget and use Positioned widget to place the Triangles at the desired position.

```
SizedBox(
  width: BOX_WIDTH,
  height: BOX_HEIGHT,
  child: Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    fit: StackFit.loose,
    children: [
    Positioned(
      top: BOX_HEIGHT/2,
      left: BOX_WIDTH/2  - side / 2,
      child: TriangleButton(side, "S"),
    ),
    Positioned(
      top: BOX_HEIGHT/2,
      left: BOX_WIDTH/2,
      child: TriangleButton(side, "SE"),
    ),
  ]
  )
)
```